# `array_agg` throwing "could not find array type for data type bigint[]"

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

In my db, the `timeline_items` table has a many-to-many relationship with `tags`, joined by the `timeline_items_tags` table. If given a list of tag ids, I want to be able to find TimelineItems that are associated with all those Tags. For instance, let's say I have a TimelineItem associated with tags 20 and 10. Given the following queries, I would expect these results:

```
[20, 10] -> OK!
[20] -> OK!
[20, 10, 33] -> NOT OK
```

Given these requirements, I attempted to write a query:

```
join(TimelineItem, :inner, [ti], tag in "timeline_items_tags", tag.timeline_item_id == ti.id and tag.tag_id in ^tag_ids) |>
group_by([ti], ti.id) |>
having([ti, tag], fragment("array_agg(?)", tag.tag_id) in ^tag_ids)
```

The first line joins any `timeline_items_tags` that match even a single tag, which is too permissive. So to ensure that all the tags are present, I attempt to group the TimelineItems and create an array of their `tag_id`. Unfortunately, this last line throws:

```
could not find array type for data type bigint[]
```

What's happening? Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was close. Needed to actually end with this line:

```
having([ti, tag], fragment("? <@ array_agg(?)", ^tag_ids, tag.tag_id))
```